# How can I use an NSRegularExpression to convert hexadecimal html entities to decimal html entities in a string of text, using Objective-C on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, regex, objective-c-blocks, nsregularexpression

How is [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:)
that is, enumerateMatchesInString, different from [this question's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475796/is-this-a-sane-objective-c-block-implementation)?

More specifically, I'm trying to use NSRegularExpression, to make a regex, to find matches in a string. Then, for each such match, I'd like to replace it with a modified version of that match. In one such situation, I'm changing hex to decimal in an HTML entity, eg &#x10 ; -> &#16 ; ). I already have PHP code that addresses the translation from hexadecimal to decimal, but I need to write basically the same method in Objective-C.

Will either or both of these two methods work for that purpose?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too difficult, the Regexp is `/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/`.

Once you have the captured number in a string, then you can use an `NSScanner`.

```
int value = NSNotFound;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:capturedHexString] scanHexInt:&value];
NSString *decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
```

Hope that helps.

---

**clarification**

I'll pull this out as a simple function

```
static inline NSString *MyDecimalStringFromHexString(NSString *hexString)
{
    unsigned value = NSNotFound;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString] scanHexInt:&value];

    NSString *decimalString = nil;

    if (value != NSNotFound)
        decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];

    return decimalString;
}
```

---

**Putting it all together**

Here is a unit test which uses the regular expression `/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/`, the category you linked, and the hex to decimal function I created to perform the substitution you want.

```
- (void)testHexEntityToDecimalEntity
{
    NSString *input = @"This &#x0A; is &#xABC; test";
    NSString *expected = @"This &#10; is &#2748; test";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\&\\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\\;" options:0 error:nil];

    NSString *actual = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length) usingBlock:^NSString *(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        NSRange hexRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
        NSString *hexString = [input substringWithRange:hexRange];
        NSString *decimalString = MyDecimalStringFromHexString(hexString);
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&#%@;", decimalString];
    }];

    STAssertEqualObjects(actual, expected, nil);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'm not so familiar with NSScanner and NSNotFound, but it looks like this is a code block that could be used in conjunction with enumerateMatchesInString. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AG I added abstracted the code into a function. It is designed to work with ARC.

Comment: So, what you're saying is I do not need to use a block, in order to systematically convert (possibly repeating) matches, but can do this simply with a function? I had been under the impression that a function could not be called from within a call to another method, but that may be me showing my ignorance.